# MySQL: filter by value in a JSON string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to implement a query that computes the distance between two pairs of lat/lgn. Assume that my lat/lng values are in a JSON string, would such a query be possible (I'm assuming some string functions might be needed first to extract lat/lng)? And if possible, is it a good idea to do it? Will it scale? Or am I better off having separate columns in the database specifically for lat/lng values?

Example JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4220352,
               "lng" : -122.0841244
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.42338418029149,
                  "lng" : -122.0827754197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4206862197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0854733802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: You can't use tools dedicated to that ? ElasticSearch, Mongodb...

Comment: Good idea: no. Scalable: no. Separate columns: yes. It is a a basic database principle to not store more than one atomic value in a column. Database normalisation: first normal form.

Comment: Is storing a JSON response in the DB a bad idea? I figured since I already had the lat/lng in the JSON, might as well use it.